# Create a Pure Wrapper for a React Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the [why-did-you-render](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render) package to debug some performance issues in my react app. I'm getting the following console message regarding why my `XDrag` component is re-rendering:

```
XDrag
defaultNotifier.js:40 {XDrag: ƒ} "Re-rendered because of props changes:"
defaultNotifier.js:45 props.children
defaultNotifier.js:49 different React elements (remember that the <jsx/> syntax always produces a *NEW* immutable React element so a component that receives <jsx/> as props always re-renders). (more info here)
defaultNotifier.js:52 {prev children: {…}} "!==" {next children: {…}}
```

In [the article linked to in this message,](https://medium.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render-mr-big-pure-react-component-part-2-common-fixing-scenarios-667bfdec2e0f) they suggest using a "pure wrapper" component around our original component to avoid this rerender:

> ```
> class PureFatherWrapper extends React.PureComponent{
>   render(){
>     return (
>       <PureFather>
>         <SomeChild/>
>       </PureFather>
>     )
>   }
> }
> ```

1. What exactly do they mean by a pure wrapper/ pure component? How is a pure component different from other kinds of components?
2. Why doe this pure wrapper avoid a re-render?
3. How could I implement a Pure Wrapper for my XDrag Component?

```js
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from "react";
import { Draggable, DraggableProps } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

interface IXDrag extends Omit<DraggableProps, "children"> {
  className?: string;
  children: ReactNode;
  dragAll?: boolean;
}

const XDrag: FC<IXDrag> = ({ className, children, dragAll, ...props }) => {
  console.log(React.isValidElement(children));
  if (!React.isValidElement(children)) return <div />;
  return (
    <Draggable {...props}>
      {(provided, snapshot) => {
        const dragHandleProps = dragAll ? provided.dragHandleProps : {};
        return (
          <tr
            className={className}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...dragHandleProps}
          >
            {React.cloneElement(children, { provided })}
          </tr>
        );
      }}
    </Draggable>
  );
};
```

Using XDrag:

```
import React from "react";
import { useStoreState } from "../../hooks";
import XDrag from "../XDrag";
import TableHeader from "./TableHeader";

const ContentTable = () => {
  const cardItems = useStoreState(
    (state) => state.appModel.activeCards
  );

  return (
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <TableHeader
                title={"URL"}
              />
            </tr>
            {cardItems.map((card, i) => {
              return (
                <XDrag
                  draggableId={card.sourceId}
                  index={i}
                  key={i.toString()}
                  isDragDisabled={card.isActive}
                >
                    <td>{card.src}</td>
                </XDrag>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
  );
};
```

Some Context:
I'm using the [react beautiful dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) library to create some draggable rows in a table. Each `XDrag` provides a `<tr>` for all the `<td>`s.

Comment: Can you also post how you are using `<XDrag>`? I mean, that parent component that renders it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer each question and hopefully give you some extra information to help you make a decision.

##### 1. What exactly do they mean by a pure wrapper/ pure component? How is a pure component different from other kinds of components?

In simple words, a pure component (or pure function) is a component (or function) that will always return the same output for the same input (by the way, this is not exclusive to React).

Example: `function add(x, y){return x + y}` is a pure function because `add(1, 2)` will always return `3`, no matter how many times you run it.

`PureComponents` have the same idea. You can read more about `PureComponents` in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

###### 2. Why does this pure wrapper avoid a re-render

In the article that you linked, this is the key part to answer this question:

> Always remember: the `<jsx prop='a'/>` syntax is just a sugar for: `React.createElement('jsx', {prop: 'a'})`. This means whenever it’s father re-renders, jsx tries to update itself with a new props object.

A `PureComponent` would know that the `prop: a` didn't change, so it would not rerender. This happens because of the [Shallow Compare](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-compare.html) utility.

##### 3. How could I implement a Pure Wrapper for my XDrag Component?

You could either use the suggestion from the article (create a PureWrapper component and use it to wrap your `<XDrag>`) or use the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook (or useMemo). Something like this:

```js
const ContentTable = () => {
  const cardItems = useStoreState((state) => state.appModel.activeCards);

  const renderCardItems = useCallback(() => {
    return cardItems.map((card, i) => {
      return (
        <XDrag draggableId={card.sourceId} index={i} key={i.toString()} isDragDisabled={card.isActive} >
          <td>{card.src}</td>
        </XDrag>
      );
    })
  }, [cardItems])
    
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <TableHeader title={"URL"} />
        </tr>
        {renderCardItems()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Here, `useCallback` has a dependency array (like `useEffect`), which means that this function only changes if `cardItems` changes. In other words, `renderCardItems()` will always return the same result as long as `cardItems` is the same.

---

### Note:

Hopefully this helped to clarify some of your questions.

That said, the real question is: **"why do you need to optimize this rerender?"**

We often worry about optimization when we don't need to. React is already pretty good with that, and browsers today have much more power. Unless you have a specific requirement or a really bad performance, you should **not add complexity** to your code just to avoid some rerenders.

In fact, "avoid early optmizations" is one clean code principle.

Here is a really good article with more information on that: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: Good answer. One thing to point out: useCallback doesn't work but useMemo will. Checkout [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-water-0sq48q)